# Doxygen: "warning: documented symbol xx was not declared or defined."

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a mixed c/c++ environment, and all my c++ class member functions gives, when I try to use Doxygen to generate documentation, this warning: `warning: documented symbol xx was not declared or defined.`

After some searching I have found that other people having this issue have solved it by setting `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` to `NO` in the Doxygen file.

This also works for me, but I really like to also be able to use doxygen for our macros, so I don't like to setting `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` to `NO`.

Anyone have an idea to how to configure Doxygen to supporting both features at the same time?

Comment: Could you describe what xx is and how macros affect it?

Comment: We need a [mcve] to understand why this is happenning.

Comment: Hi Nicol. Thanks for forcing me to make a minimal example :). That pointed me in the right direction. Turns out the I had to set "PREDEFINED  = __cplusplus", because I have #ifdef __cplusplus in the header file.